# Piping emails from a development server to a text file

Tags: centos, email, pipe, development

Is there a way to capture all mail from a unix server and pipe it to a log file? Or maybe at least all mail from PHP? I know of a trick where in php.ini sendmail is tricked byt this line:

```
sendmail_path = /Users/ckj/Dropbox/scripts/snydmail.sh
```

Where snydmail.sh just looks like this:

```
cat >> /path/to/file/mails.txt
```

This works fine on my local MAMP server, but I cannot get it working on my CentOS server.

Has anyone got a more clever way than the hack above?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have procmail installed? If so, you could use a recipe like the following:

```
  :0c:
/path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: I do! I'll give that a try. I never fiddled with procmail, so any newbie-link to configuring would be a big help :)

Comment: Procmail is really useful - try [here](http://www.vglug.info/complete-sendmail-configuration-rhel-4-5-fedora-linux-open-source) for a useful link about implementing it. I assume that installing it is as simple as `yum install procmail` but would normally work on debian instead of centos.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Just to make sure I get it. We are talking about outgoing mail from my development sever. I was maybe a bit unclear about that.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider procmail.  It is well designed to filter mail and send it to various mailboxes, or files.  I think it will do exactly what you want and beyond, more elegantly.